# How to express window function in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I am new to Slick and I am having hard time to express SQL window function in Slick. My database profile is SQL Server so I cannot use slick-pg.

The problem that I want to solve is simple in SQL (below). Essentially, it is just to find the largest `rowid` for each `destination`. How to write in this in Slick?

```
select rowid, destination 
from (
    select rowid
          , destination
          , row_number() over (partition by destination order by rowid desc) as rowOrder 
    from DestinationTable
)
where rowOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check user defined functions in slick,
https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.0/userdefined.html

Here is an example, I achieved same requirement using SimpleLiteral, ideally SimpleFunction might be good choice, but SimpleLiteral works for my use case.

and used a subquery to filter over rowNum data.

```
 val rowNumCol = SimpleLiteral[Int]("ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY replaceGroupByColumnName order by sortColumnName desc)")
    val innerQueryRowNum = queryFilter.map(jb => (jb.guid, rowNumCol))
    val resultQueryFilter = TableQuery.join(innerQueryRowNum).on((tb, tbs) => tb.guid === tbs._1).filter(tb => tb._2._2 === 1).map(tb => tb._1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slick does not support this functionality in its query DSL, so you'll need to use Slick's support for plain SQL queries.

http://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.3/sql.html